# Getting the error "urllist is empty,fail to remoteTranslate" in HMS ML Kit while translating text?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

In HMS ML Kit  I am getting an error "urllist list is empty, fail to remoteTranslate" while translating text from Spanish to English. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This error comes if you skip any initial set up. Please make sure

1. You have integrated all necessary dependencies in root level and app level build.gradle.
2. You have set the data storage location in AGC.
3. You have enabled ML kit in Manage APIs.
4. You have downloaded agconnect-services.json and integrated in your project.